# Exactly Matched NSString in Core Data iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've my entity in CoreData named as `myentity` and an attribute named as `myuniqueid` and I want to run an SQL query as follows:

```
Select * from myentity where myuniqueid == 1000
```

How can I get my specified rows where it matches as in SQL query? such that I want to filter all rows where `myuniqueid` is `1000`.

**My Code:**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (context == nil) {}
    else {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myentity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myuniqueid == 1000"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            NSManagedObject *mo = [items objectAtIndex:i];  // assuming that array is not empty
            id value = [mo valueForKey:@"myuniqueid"];
            NSLog(@"SENDER: %@",value);
        }

    }
```

Im getting error: `'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (myuniqueid == 1000) (problem on RHS)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this predicate :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"myentity"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myuniqueid == %@", @(1000)];
NSArray *items = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```